# Solve a backward-forward equation with a loop

Tags: recursion, core-language, infinite-loop

I want to solve this recursive equation

```
X[t+1] = 0.8  X[t] + 0.04 P[t+1] + 119.6;
P[t_] := 0.4 X[t] + 0.8 P[t + 1];
P[t_] := S[t] X[t] - g[t];
```

and with these conditions

```
X[1] = 1;
p[11] = 0;
S[11] = 0;
g[10] = 0;
g[11] = 0;
S[10] = 0.4;
```

I want to obtain `x[2], ..., x[10]` and `p[1], ..., p[10]`

I have defined these loops

```
For[j = 10, j >= 1, j--, P[j] = P[j]; S[j] = S[j]; g[j] = g[j]];
For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++, X[j] = X[j]]
```

but they do not give the results I expect.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please format your code for readability; here are some pointers: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: i defined this loop

Comment: For[j = 10, j >= 1, j--, P[j] = P[j]; S[j] = S[j]; g[j] = g[j]];
For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++, X[j] = X[j]]

Comment: somayeh, it would be best if you included the code you posted in the comment, in your own question. you can edit your question at any time; use the "edit" link that appears at the bottom left of the question's text. When you do that, you could also format the code in your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using Table and Reduce instead of For, but using your equations as given.

```
X[1]=1; p[11]=0; S[11]=0; g[10]=0; g[11]=0; S[10]=.4;
Cases[Reduce[Flatten[Table[{
    X[t + 1] == 0.8 X[t] + 0.04 P[t + 1] + 119.6, 
    P[t] == 0.4 X[t] + 0.8 P[t + 1],
    P[t] == S[t] X[t] - g[t]},
    {t, 1, 10}]], Flatten[Table[{x[t], P[t]}, {t, 2, 10}]]], 
  X[_]==_ | P[_]==_]
```

which responds with

```
{X[11] == 608.601, X[10] == 611.251, X[9] == 602.339, X[8] == 581.597,
 X[7] == 548.403, X[6] == 501.761, X[5] == 440.272, X[4] == 362.091,
 X[3] == 264.873, X[2] == 145.701,
 P[11] == 0, P[1] == 506.42, P[2] == 632.525, P[3] == 717.806,
 P[4] == 764.821, P[5] == 774.98, P[6] == 748.589, P[7] == 684.856,
 P[8] == 581.868, P[9] == 436.536, P[10] == 244.501}
```

with one warning that Reduce needed to turn your approximate numbers into exact.

I'm a little surprised and impressed that with 18 "variables" that it reduces in an instant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have question about this line of program   X[_]==_ | P[_]==_], would you please explain it?

Comment: @somayeh If you position your cursor just before the final ] and left click the mouse then MMA should change the color of the ] and the opening [ which shows the last line of the code is the second argument to Cases. If you look at the documentation for Cases you see it extracts items that match a pattern. Thus I created a pattern to match X[n]== or P[n]== in the solution from Reduce. Carefully remove the Cases and the last  line to see the result then includes undesired solutions g[n]==. Carefully study all this, take it apart, learn from how it works.